# How to set categorical attributes to vertex in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to set a bunch of categorical attributes as an attribute to a vertex and then color the nodes based on their type. When I try to pass the attribute to the graph, I get a warning saying

```
"In vattrs[[name]][index] <- value :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
```

I even made the attribute into a character, yet the warning shows up.

```
V(g4)$affiliation<-as.character(join4$Affiliation)
```

I have 4 types of categories but when I try to pass them as an attribute they are converted into only two types.

```
head(join4)
   Source Destination      Affiliation
2       2          25          Liberal
3       2          25          Liberal
4       2          25          Liberal
25     23          23 Slightly liberal
26     23          23 Slightly liberal
27     24          58          Liberal

tail(join4)

      Source      Destination    Affiliation
100     46          44           Extremely liberal
101     46          44           Extremely liberal
102     46          32           Extremely liberal
107     51          51 Moderate middle of the road
108     51          51 Moderate middle of the road
113     57          57                     Liberal
```

As you can see all the nodes become either liberal or slightly liberal

```
g4<-graph.data.frame(join4,directed=F)
V(g)$affiliation<-as.character(join4$Affiliation)

 V(g4)$affiliation
 [1] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
 [3] "Liberal"          "Slightly liberal"
 [5] "Slightly liberal" "Liberal"         
 [7] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
 [9] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[11] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[13] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[15] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[17] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[19] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[21] "Liberal"          "Liberal"         
[23] "Liberal"
```

I would like the respective category to be associated with the respective name. How can I do this?

Comment: The code that you provided tries to set the affiliation for _g_ `V(g)$affiliation<-as.character(join4$Affiliation)`  but then you display the affiliation for _g4_ `V(g4)$affiliation`  Are you getting two different graphs confused?

Comment: sorry that was a typo.

Comment: What do you get from `length(join4$Affiliation)`  and `vcount(g4)` ?

Comment: vcount is 23, and the length is 67.

Comment: Well,  that is why you get the warning.  You need to have one affiliation per vertex.

Comment: I did ```g4<-simplify(g4,edge.attr.comb = list(weight="sum", "ignore"))``` to reduce the same repeated interactions, but there are still certain unique interactions. How can I resolve this?